# Will hostile NPCs remain hostile forever (after theft)?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I was in the Vorm lodge and stole a book I needed for a quest. They caught me and immediately decided to attack, so I ran. I have two open quests for people in the lodge however. I did the quest but whe I returned they were still hostile. Is there anyway, or any time after which, they will not longer be hostile and I can complete the quest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, after a few game days have passed, they will eventually become neutral and will no longer attack you until you commit your next crime.